# Copy Specific Rows from workbook into x amount of new workbooks (one per row), pasting as format/values only

Tags: excel, vba

Beginner in VBA.
What I'm attempting to do:

- Copy the first 5 rows _ row 'x' in current worksheet, and paste in a new workbook
- New workbooks should be saved in the same directory
- This should repeat for every row below the first 5, i.e. rows 1-5 + 6, rows 1-5 + 7, rows 1-5 + 8, etc.
- When pasting the rows into the new workbook, I don't want to copy formulas, just format and values

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim MyBook As Workbook, newBook As Workbook
    Dim FileNm As String

    Set MyBook = ThisWorkbook

    FileNm = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "TEST-BOOK.xlsx"
    Set newBook = Workbooks.Add

    With newBook
        MyBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("1:5").Copy .Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("1")

        'Save new wb
        .SaveAs Filename:=FileNm, CreateBackup:=False

        .Close Savechanges:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

It copies the rows 1-5, but I don't know how to add the dynamic extra row-- it also copies all the formulas and embeds them. Assuming the Filename would also have to be in some sort of loop?
Thank you.

Comment: So to be clear... if you got 10 rows, you want 6 new workbooks. 1 for the first 5 rows and then copy the first 5 rows and each row below the 5 in a new workbook. right?

Comment: Yes, exactly that! I mean the first 5 rows are like the headers, so I want them copied into every new workbook. And then the remaining 5 rows should be copied, one each, into new workbooks (with the headers rows 1-5). Workbook 1= Rows 1-6 ;  Workbook 2= Rows 1-5 + 7; Workbook 3 = Rows 1-5 + 8, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this helps,

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim wb As Workbook, FileNm As String, LastRow As Long, Headers As Range, wbTemp As Workbook, i As Long

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    'lets suppose your data is in the first worksheet of your book
    With wb
        LastRow = .Sheets(1).Cells(.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 5 'this is to count how many rows you've got
        Set Headers = .Sheets(1).Rows("1:5") 'set the headers to copy them every iteration
    End With

    'copy each row + headers in a new workbook
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        FileNm = wb.Path & "\" & "TEST-BOOK" & i & ".xlsx" 'add the i to number every workbook from 1 to extra rows you have
        Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Add 'add a new workbook
        Headers.Copy 
        wbTemp.Sheets(1).Rows(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'paste the headers
        wb.Sheets(1).Rows(5 + i).Copy 
        wbTemp.Sheets(1).Rows(6).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'copy the next row in the iteration
        wbTemp.SaveAs FileNm
        wbTemp.Close
        Set wbTemp = Nothing
    Next i

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This did 99% of the work, thank you! I just had to define the variable 'i', (Dim i as Long) for the loop to work.

Comment: Aside from that, the only thing it's not doing is pasting the rows with format/values only. It's still linking some embedded formulas to the original workbook (which when sent out to third parties, will not display the correct data). What would the workaround for that be? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry @Tester_Y I had a brainfart there thinking it would only copy values. Now is sorted. Remember to mark it as an answer if it solves everything so someone else can find it.